# Double integral of an off-centered circle.

Tags: multivariable-calculus, polar-coordinates, multiple-integral

I'm new to double integral and doing this problem: (from the Supplemental Problems, MIT)

Express each double integral over the given region R as an iterated integral in polar
coordinates. Use the method described in Notes I to supply the limits of integration. For
some of them, it may be necessary to break the integral up into two parts. In each case,
begin by sketching the region.

b) The circle of radius 1, and center at (0, 1).

What I have done so far:

Since I know the area of a radius 1 circle is $\pi$, the result must also be $\pi$.

I know the bounds must be from 0 to $\pi$. Then, I do the following double integral:

$$\int_0^{\pi}\int_0^{2sin\theta} 1 drd\theta $$

But the result is 4, which is a wrong answer.

Therefore, my question is, where is the mistake? I do try to replace the $drd\theta$ term to $rdrd\theta$ and it gives me the correct answer, which is $\pi$.

But there are some problems, which do not use the $rdrd\theta$ term. For example, this problem:

a) The region lying inside the circle with center at the origin and radius 2. and to the left of the vertical line through (−1, 0).

[image]

The answer of this problem is:

$$\int_{2\pi/3}^{4\pi/3} \int_{-sec\theta}^2 1 drd\theta$$

which does not include a $rdrd\theta$ term

Furthermore, I will appreciate if anyone can help me to point out when to use the $drd\theta$ term and when to use $rdrd\theta$ term.

P/S: Sorry for my bad English. I'm not a native speaker.

Comment: Your question - "I will appreciate if anyone can help me to point out when to use the $ dr \ d\theta$ term and when to use $ r \ dr \ d\theta$ term? When you convert from area element $dx \ dy$ in cartesian to area element in polar coordinates, you use substitution $x = r \cos\theta, y = r\sin\theta$ and Jacobian for the change of variable is $r$. So you should use $r \ dr \ d\theta$. Any specific reason you ask when to use $dr \ d\theta$?

Comment: Just updated the question, thanks!

Comment: Your second integral is not correct. First of all, it is a circle centered at the origin then why is the upper bound of $r$  $2\sin\theta$? In any case, it should also have $r$ Jacobian.

Comment: Sorry, it should be correct now.

Comment: You need to use the Jacobian even in second integral. See my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I mentioned in comments, when you convert area element from cartesian into polar, it should have Jacobian $r$ for the change of variable.

In both examples of yours, you should use the Jacobian $r$.

The first integral is,

$ \displaystyle \int_0^{\pi} \int_0^{2\sin\theta} r \ dr \ d\theta = \pi$

The second integral is,

$\displaystyle \int_{2\pi/3}^{4\pi/3} \int_{-sec\theta}^2 r \ dr \ d\theta = \frac{4\pi}{3} - \sqrt3$

Comment: The answer is provided from MIT, which can be found here (problem 3B-1 a and b) . I don't think the answer is wrong because two following answers also are not used $rdrd\theta$  https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/mathematics/18-02sc-multivariable-calculus-fall-2010/3.-double-integrals-and-line-integrals-in-the-plane/part-a-double-integrals/problem-set-7/MIT18_02SC_SupProbSol3.pdf

Comment: I checked. That is a bad mistake from them / a typo. Do they have answer?

Comment: I did. Please check it.

Comment: This is the problem link: https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/mathematics/18-02sc-multivariable-calculus-fall-2010/3.-double-integrals-and-line-integrals-in-the-plane/part-a-double-integrals/problem-set-7/MIT18_02SC_SupProb3.pdf

Comment: Again as I mentioned, they have typos in answer. You must have Jacobian $r$. Please do not get confused just looking at some typos.

Comment: I went through the question. In $3B-2(a)$, they are evaluating $\int \frac{dA}{r}$ so there $r$ will get canceled but not in $3B-1(a)$.

Comment: please see $3B-2(a)$

Comment: The reason I post this is 3B -2 a) since I did without r then got a diverge integral.

Comment: why would you get a diverge integral? I thought you said you got an answer of $4$?

Comment: The 4 answer is my result from 3B -1b. But for 3B-2a) I got $$\int_0^{\pi/2} \int_0^{sin2\theta} dA/r$$

Comment: I have already spent sometime trying to explain to you. If you want to understand, be specific in your question. Just because you have link from somewhere, be it MIT, which made a mistake in not typing in $r$, does not change the fact.

Comment: To your edited comment, yes $dA = r \ dr \ d\theta$ so $\frac{dA}{r} = dr \ d\theta$. That integral is not divergent!

Comment: Thanks. For that, I also assume dA= $drd\theta$, which gives the wrong answer.

Comment: please always remember $dA = r \ dr \ d\theta$

Comment: Thanks for your reply.

Answer (score 1):

Since you are working in polar coordinates, you must add the area element, which is $r$. So, what you should actually compute is$$\int_0^\pi\int_0^{2\sin\theta}r\,\mathrm dr\,\mathrm d\theta(=\pi).$$

Comment: Sorry, it is my mistake, but I have seen some problem that does not include a $rdrd\theta$ term (I included in my edited post). So can you please check it out and explain it? Thanks.

Comment: The number $\displaystyle\int_{2\pi/3}^{4\pi/3}\int_0^{2\sin\theta}1\,\mathrm dr\,\mathrm d\theta$ is equal to $0$, and therefore it cannot possibly be the area of that region, which is$$\int_{2\pi/3}^{4\pi/3}\int_{-1}^{2\cos\theta}r\,\mathrm dr\,\mathrm d\theta=\frac{\sqrt3}2+\frac\pi3.$$

Comment: Sorry, it should be correct now.

Comment: I have no idea about the origin of that new integral, and it seems that each time that I answer your question you changed it into another question. Do you find that behavior appropriate?

Comment: If I was you, I would be angry too. Sorry for that.

Answer (score 0):

Let me suggest idea of "shifted" polar coordinates: while original one is $$x=\rho \cos \phi,\\ y= \rho \sin \phi$$ then we can consider $$x-x_0=\rho \cos \phi,\\ y-y_0= \rho \sin \phi$$ This do not change Jakobian, but makes more easy to obtain angles for disks with center not in $(0,0)$. For example, for your case b) The circle of radius $1$, and center at $(0, 1)$ is good to consider $x_0=1, y_0=0$.